# heroku can't push references

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

```
Installing node-v6.11.1-linux-x64
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       SyntaxError:         /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/config/routes.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
   /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
   /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
   /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
   /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
   /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `block in load_paths'
   /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `each'
   /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `load_paths'
   /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:18:in `reload!'
   /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `block in updater'
   /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:81:in `execute'
   /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:42:in `updater'
   /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:31:in `execute_if_updated'
   /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:128:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
   /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
   /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
   /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
   /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:329:in `require'
   /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:329:in `require_environment!'
   /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:445:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
   /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_fdfdda041ac97232ad8bd0b00c54c482/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-    12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

Super new to this stuff, following this tutorial: http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/deploy_a_rails_app

I'm not sure why I am getting this precompile error here after entering command "git push heroku master". Also when I look in the tmp folder for the file that throws the syntax error, it doesn't show up (probably because it goes away after running the command).

In my routes.rb file I have:

```
root 'drinks#index'
resources :drinks
# For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post your `config/routes.rb` file.

Comment: @TomAranda just added routes.rb code

Comment: if that is the entire contents of your `routes.rb`, then it indeed is syntactically invalid. What do you think it is that `end` closes?

Comment: We need the whole file including the first line.  Also what version of Rails are you using?

Comment: That is the whole routes.rb file (i suppose it seems weird to have "end" there), also I am using Rails 5.1.4 and ruby 2.3.4p301 [i686-linux]. I tried removing end but I still get the same errors.

Comment: @TomAranda could this be happening because I have x64 linux and ruby is specified for i686-linux? Phrasing on that sentence may not be the best.

Comment: Is that your entire routes file? Do you have `Rails.application.routes.draw do
` at the top?

Comment: @TomAranda yes that's the whole thing. I never wrote it though, it was just auto generated and that's what was in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have a syntax error in your `routes.rb`.  The parser is finding an `end` with no corresponding `do` (beginning). Your complete `routes.rb` should look like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'drinks#index'
  resources :drinks
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: So should that Rails.application.routes.draw line be generated automatically?

Comment: I am not sure what you used for code generation.  I would think `rails new` would generate it.